# Contract words in python with set length

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to make a sort of "word mixer": for two given words and the desired length specified, the program should return the "mix" of the two words. However, it can be any sort of mix: it can be the first half of the first word combined with the second half of the second word, it can be a random mix, anything really.

Examples:

fish + cake, length 5: fiske

dog + cat, length 4: doga

late + cross, length 6: losste

I've written a very sloppy code (as seen below), and I'd appreciate some tips on what am I doing wrong (since my outputs aren't really good) and if there's anything that can be improved.

```
from random import randint

name1 = "domingues"
name2 = "signorelli"
names = [name1,name2]
# a list of the desired lengths
lengths = [5,6,7]
mixes = []

def sizes(size):
    if size == 5:
        letters1 = randint(2,3)
    else:
        letters1 = randint(2,size-2)
    letters2 = size-letters1
    return letters1, letters2

def mix(letters1, letters2):
    n = randint(0,1)
    if n == 1:
        a = 0
    else:
        a = 1
    n1 = names[n]
    n2 = names[a]
    result = n1[0:letters2]+n2[-letters1::]
    return result

file = open("results.txt","w+")
for leng in lengths:
    file.write("RESULTS WITH "+str(leng)+" LETTERS \n")
    file.write("\n")
    for i in range(10):
        let1, let2 = sizes(leng)
        result = mix(let1,let2)
        while result == name1 or result == name2:
            result = mix(let2)
        if result not in mixes:
            mixes.append(result)
    for m in mixes:
        if m not in file:
            file.write(m+" \n")
            file.write("\n")
file.close()
```

(Thanks for taking your time to help me btw, I appreciate it!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this is AI-related problem, because we are implicitly want to get readable mixed words. 
I just wrote simple (and dirty) code that tries to catch sequences of vowels and consonants from training data and builds mixed words according to catched rules.

```
import random

consonants_pat = 'BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVXZ'.lower()
vowels_pat = 'aeiouy'

train_data = '''
                This our sentence to be used as a training dataset
                It should be longer
                '''

def build_mixer(train_data, num=3, mixed_len=(2, 4)):

    def _get_random_pattern(td, wlen):
        td_splitted = td.lower().split()
        while True:
            w = random.choice(list(filter(lambda x: len(x)>=wlen, td_splitted)))
            for j in range(len(w)-wlen):
                yield tuple(map(lambda x: 0 if x in vowels_pat else 1,  w[j:j + wlen]))

    def _select_vowels(w):
        return 


    def _mixer(w1, w2, num=num, mixed_len=mixed_len):
        allowed_letters = w1.lower().strip() + w2.lower().strip()
        ind = 1
        for j in range(num):
            wlen = random.choice(range(*mixed_len))
            pattern = _get_random_pattern(train_data, wlen)
            _aux = allowed_letters
            word = ''
            try:
                for pat in pattern:
                    for k in pat:
                        if k == 0:
                            choiced = random.choice(list(filter(lambda x: x in vowels_pat,  _aux)))
                            word += choiced
                        else:
                            choiced = random.choice(list(filter(lambda x: x in consonants_pat,  _aux)))
                            word += choiced
                        l = list(_aux)
                        l.remove(choiced)
                        _aux = ''.join(l)
                    ind += 1
                    yield word
                    if ind>num:
                        raise StopIteration
            except IndexError:
                continue

    return _mixer


mixer = build_mixer(train_data, num=6, mixed_len=(3,6))
for mixed in mixer('this', 'horse'):
    print(mixed)
```

I got the following words:

> het hetihs hetihssro sheo hsio tohir

Comment: I like the idea of making a training sample in order for it to "learn" what is readable, I'll try implementing this... does the training data have to be a string or can it be a list?

Comment: You can choose content of some book as training data.  It should be previously cleaned up from special chars, such as `!;-...` etc. Word mixing algorithm could be significantly improved to catch more thin relationships between letters and syllables.

Comment: I see, I'll try to implement it using some sentences, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend taking a random slice of the word string and combining it with another random slice from the second word. Get the `len(word)` and take a slice of the word randomly using `random.randrange()`.

```
import random

def word_mixer(word1, word2):
    slice1 = word1[:random.randrange(2, len(word1))]
    slice2 = word2[:random.randrange(2, len(word2))]
    return slice1 + slice2

mixed = word_mixer('weasel', 'snake')
print(mixed)
```

Output:

```
wesnak
weasesna
weassnak
```

Comment: This is a nice idea, I changed `slice2` to be `slice2 = word2[random.randrange(2, len(word2)):]` so it could fit what I wanted. As bubble said, it's an AI problem (making readable mixed strings), but this at least gives me a start. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could be of service. Good luck my friend!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.

```
import random
w1 = 'dog'
w2 = 'cat'
w3 = 'fish'
w4 = 'wolf'


def word_mixer(w1, w2, length):
    new_word = w1 + w2
    x = random.sample(range(len(new_word)), length)
    result = []
    for i in x:
        result.append(new_word[i])

    return "".join(result)

print(word_mixer(w3,w4,4))
print(word_mixer(w2,w4,5))
```

Output:

```
lfwi                                                                                                                                  
falwc
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more smaller version of @AkshayNevrekar's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54977238/8472377):

```
import random

w1 = 'dog'
w2 = 'cat'
w3 = 'fish'
w4 = 'wolf'

def word_mixer(w1, w2, length):
    return ''.join(random.sample(w1 + w2, length))

print(word_mixer(w3, w4, 4))
print(word_mixer(w2, w4, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `random.sample` and pass mixed string to it like this:

```
import random
w1=input("Enter first word")
w2=input("Enter second word")
len=int(input("Enter length"))
mixed=w1+w2

def wordmixer(mixed,len):
    return ''.join(random.sample(mixed,len))

print(wordmixer(mixed,len))
```

Comment: This will fail if the len is larger than sample.